# Keychain always asks for password

Tags: macos, keychain

I am not on a network but my IT person at work set up my MacBook Pro for me to take home.

Nearly every time I try to make a move between apps or open up anything new I am asked to give a password for the Keychain. I have spoken to others in my group who use Macs at home and they think I am nuts.

What is the purpose of that? How can I disable Keychain asking me all the time?

Comment: Can you explain in which situations exactly you're asked for a password? (Also, wouldn't you rather ask this question the IT staff who set it up?)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.  I solved it by changing the 'settings for keychain 'login'. It was set to prompt after 5 minutes or upon screenlock...

Comment: I was plagued by this too.  Right click on 'login' in the Keychain Access and select 'Change settings for keychain "login" ...'  I unchecked both "Lock after 5 minutes of inactivity", and "Lock when sleeping"

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the password for the login-Keychain to the same password you use to log into the mac. Then on logging in the keychain will automatically be unlocked and you will not need to unlock the keychain everytime an application wants to read an entry from it.

To do so

- Open up `/Applications/Utilities/KeychainAccess` (I'm doing this out of the head, so please excuse translation issues or slight inaccuracies)
- Go to the Menu-Item `Edit` and select `Change password for keychain 'login'`.

You will have to give the current password and then the login-password for the mac.

Hope that helps.